# Mysql - select with where in clause with additional condition?

Tags: conditional-statements

This is the table:

*rulestbl

```
|  idrule  |  idsys  |  orders |
--------------------------------
|R01#1     |    1    |    1    |
|R01#1     |    2    |    1    |
|R01#2     |    1    |    2    |
|R01#2     |    3    |    2    |
|R01#2     |    4    |    2    |
|R01#3     |    2    |    3    |
|R01#3     |    1    |    3    |
|R01#3     |    5    |    3    |
|R01#4     |    1    |    4    |
|R01#4     |    4    |    4    |
|R01#4     |    5    |    4    |
--------------------------------
```

I want to select with 2 condition in one input array, if I want to input (`idsys = 1` and `idsys = 2`) and `"where orders" = MIN()`  so the output should be:

```
|  idrule  |  orders  |
----------------------
|R01#1     |   1     |
----------------------
```

anyone can help me? thanks

the result one should be elimination only "idsys with conditon 1 and 2" so the result is shoud be :

```
|   idrule  |  orders  |
-----------------------
|R01#1      |    1    |
|R01#3      |    3    |
-----------------------
```

and this is the syntax for first elimination :

```
SELECT idrule
FROM rulestbl
WHERE idsys IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY idrule
HAVING count(*) = 2
```

so next we elimination MIN(order) is 1 so the finally result is :

```
|   idrule  |  orders  |
------------------------
|R01#1      |    1     |
------------------------
```

Comment: thx ndn...btw any answer can help me?

Answer (score 0):

This should work ;-)

```
SELECT X.IDRULE, MIN(X.ORDERS) FROM rulestbl,
(
SELECT idrule, orders
FROM rulestbl
WHERE idsys IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY idrule
HAVING count(*) = 2
) X
WHERE X.idrule = rulestbl.idrule
```

inside IN clause you can split your array.

Good luck

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

Comment: and if you need you can group result using group by clause select idrule, orders, min(orders) where idsys in (1, 2) group by  idrule, orders;

Comment: Hi bud, I've created one table with your data and ran the query, my result seems to be good. Try it just changing your table name: select idrule, min(orders) as 'order'
from test
where idsys in (1, 2);

Comment: no mate, the "and" condition not working mate....it would be "false", PLEASE check my question again, I have the syntax for first elimination...the both condition of idsys 1 and 2 shoud work...not only 1 or 2...

Comment: sorry, can't get it. there is no "and" condition in my query

Comment: mate, actually the data in my question is simple, I have a big data in real case, so in your answer the "and" condition is not working, idsys 1 and 2 must match with "and" condtion, not 1 or 2 only with match...in your answer when I try, another values which have 1 or 2 also elected in first elimination... so in my question "idrule R01#2 and R01#4 is also" selected.

Comment: the answer is almost working, the field (orders ) is right, but IDRULE is not follow the orders MIN() function

Comment: better than before... just updated with small modifications, the result changed here with sample data, don't know for you how it will be presented. Try out. Is quite hard not seeing the real database

Comment: i try to sent the real database in image, but I can't because the rule in this forums, I have must 10 reputation for post the image, but your answer is almost right....but not yet.. :(